# Redux devtools -> Typescript objects represented as strings instead of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example if I have a state like so :

```
let initialState = {
     s : Settings 
}
```

And in a typescript file :

```
export class Settings {
    messageProfiles: boolean
    max: number
}
```

-> In the extension, s will be represented as a string instead of as an Object :

```
"{"messageProfiles":true,"max":0}"
```

But when I console.log the store.getState() it shows an Object so I know it doesn't come from my code.

Is that normal? How can I show object instead of stringified version?

Edit - my redux config :

```
   const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
     realtime: true,
     port: 8383
   });

   const store = createStore(
     rootReducer,
     composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware))
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

In order the extension to handle unserializable by JSON.stringify data (like dates, regexes, undefined, error objects, symbols and functions) just set serialize parameter to true:

Example:

```
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__({
   serialize: true
}));
```

Comment: Hey thanks what about with my createstore config? I tried to add serialize: true the option doesn't exist (see my config in the edit)

Comment: Different config options : https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#windowdevtoolsextensionconfig